# allow twig syntax in htmlpurifier and/or don't tidy

Tags: twig, htmlpurifier

i am running some templates my visitors make with twig through htmlpurifier but it keeps trying to fix the html code.

i have this as an example:

```
<ul>
   {% for update in jobupdates %}
       <li>
          {{ update.comment|nl2br }}
       </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and it will turn that into:

```
<ul><li>
{% for update in jobupdates %}
</li><li>
    {{ update.comment|nl2br }}
{% endfor %}
</li></ul>
```

which totaly breaks it all.
I have tried setting the option 'HTML.TidyLevel' to none but it still does it.

Is there i way to stop htmlpurifier from trying to fix the html code? or to ignore twig syntax?

Answer (score 2):

### Background

#### Is HTML Purifier the right tool for the job you want to do?

Your problem essentially boils down to that HTML Purifier is designed to sanitise HTML, whereas you are feeding it Twig, a templating mark-up language. It *contains* some HTML, but that's not the same thing as *being* HTML (much like HTML can *contain* plain text, but is not the same thing as plain text).

#### Why is this happening?

The reason it's doing what you're observing is that much of HTML Purifier's strength in the sanitising department comes from being strict about the structure of the HTML that is fed to it. That way, exploits that depend on implementation details in browsers which lay outside the standard (such as in this case how to handle text in an *unordered list* (`<ul>`) that is not a *list item* (`<li>`)) are also taken care of, reducing the attack surface.

In this particular case, the chance that anything would break by allowing this constellation is so small as to be negligible, but one can imagine other constellations where it does matter (e.g. imagine someone writing `<img>some payload here</img>` - that makes no sense in HTML, and I know of no exploit in the wild right now that looks anything like this, but one could imagine a browser trying to get clever with it).

Either way, it's an integral part of HTML Purifier and you can't simply turn it off, as all of the sanitation rules HTML Purifier has essentially exist *on top* of having well-formed HTML, for the mentioned reason.

### Solutions

#### A: Question the use-case

Depending on what your penultimate use-case for sanitation is, the solution may be as simple as to put the purification *after* your Twig template has been turned into HTML, but *before* the result is displayed on the page. This has the added benefit of purifying e.g. the comments that are injected into your template.

That said, this may have no relation to what you're actually hoping to achieve.

#### B: Use a different tool

If all you want to do is *tidy* the HTML in your templates rather than *sanitise* it, you may want to look into a different tool. I have no experience with tools that just tidy HTML and they may have the same shortfalls (even just wanting to produce valid HTML is going to have that effect - but perhaps there are tools out there which *only indent* the tags and fix up obvious tag errors like removing a stray `</img>` somewhere).

If you want to *sanitise* your HTML, you can try a different tool as well. Take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison for some ideas?

#### C: Alter HTML Purifier's HTML definition

You can fork HTML Purifier and make changes to its understanding of HTML. This is really only feasible if the example in your post does not have many cousins, i.e. if there are not many completely different constellations where the insistence on well-formed HTML gets in the way. In the example you mentioned, this likely requires digging into the guts of `HTMLPurifier_HTMLModule_List` and `HTMLPurifier_ChildDef_List`, specifically into the `else`-block in `validateChildren()` from the latter class, but I have no proof-of-concept on hand right now.

Keep in mind what you'd be doing here is essentially turning the HTML definition that HTML Purifier works with into a rudimentary Twig definition. Not only is that potentially a lot of work (depending on how much you want to teach it), it's probably not actually what you want to do.

### Conclusion

I'd recommend asking yourself a few questions and taking action based on the answers (the information in brackets exists as a guide to those actions, the thoughts there are *not* exhaustive):

1. **Is it essential for you to have clean templates or clean output?** *(If templates, HTML Purifier can't help you, as it's not made for Twig; if output, HTML Purifier can help you.)*
2. **Do you want to prevent XSS attacks?** *(If you do, HTML Purifier can help you, but only after Twig has done its thing and constructed HTML for it to analyse.)*
3. **Do you want to catch invalid HTML declarations?** *(If you do, again HTML Purifier can help you, but also only after Twig has done its thing.)*
4. **Do you want to catch invalid Twig declarations?** *(If you do, HTML Purifier cannot help you - it might make sense to look for a Twig-specific validation tool.)*

There are other questions you can ask yourself, but I hope those provide a useful starting point.

Comment: thats for your help.... but the way i see it is... the twig code should be treated as normal text not any code at all. just like in a standard html page. And then the html cleaning should be disabled, as i don't need it cleaned.  and wola, i should have it working. But i just can't seem to disable to cleaning in htmlpurifier. From the docs it seems the html tidy is what i doing it, but after i set it to 'none' it still trys to fix the html.

Comment: I agree with pinkgothic, the only valable options here is to use the purifier after the render of twig. I can think of situations where the template inside twig is not "correct", but once rendered it is.